# how to search and append value in array inside array

Tags: arrays, swift

i have this input

```
let teachersInfo: [[String]] = [
      ["names", "comments"],
      ["Ian", "scientist,male, no_available"],
      ["Mark", "teacher,elementary school,female, available_for_new"],
      ["Bryan", "interior designer,male,no_available"],
      ["Tomas", "profesional surfer,master"],
      ["Justine", "no_available, scientist"],
      ["Malek", "teacher, elementary school, available_for_new"],
      ["Adrian", "scientist, profesional surfer, available_for_new"],  
      ["Mike", "elementary schoole,male,no_available"]
    ]
```

i want to create a function for search and append a value when it founds a match for
for example

```
func addnewValuesForTeachers(teacherName: String, newValues: String){
    if teachersInfo.contains(teacherName){
        //for example if teacherName was 'Ian' and newValues are "technician"
        //should look like
        //["Ian", "**technician** , scientist,male, no_available"]
    }
    
}
```

i know can insert values like this:

```
teachersInfo[0].insert(name, at: position)
```

Comment: You should structure your data. Create a new struct with two properties and an array with those elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would restructure this into real structs with properties, but if you want to stay with this `[[String]]` you would need to get the index of your array. Then replace that `String` with the value you want to add plus the original `String`:

```
func addnewValuesForTeachers(teacherName: String, newValues: String){
    guard let index = teachersInfo.firstIndex(where: { item in
        item[0] == teacherName
    }) else {
        return
    }
    
    teachersInfo[index][1] = "\(newValues), \(teachersInfo[index][1])"
}
```

[image: proof]

Comment: it may not be on 0th index brother.. you are assuming ?

Comment: @JawadAli please look at the data structure. Your answer is wrong.

Comment: Hello thank you for answer but it's adding the new value in the same spot as the first  value not separeten with a , example: 
["Ian", "**NEWVALUE**scientist,male, no_available"],

Comment: That shouldn´t be too much of a problem. Please see my updated answer